# Convert Android Java code to Xamarin C#

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I get a problem with converting code from native Android JAVA code to Xamarin C# Android code

I have a class which shall help me to delay start in my custom `AutoComleteTextView` searching:

```
public class DelayAutoCompleteTextView : AutoCompleteTextView
{
    public static Context _Context {get; set;}
    private static Android.Util.IAttributeSet _Attrs { get; set; }

public DelayAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
{
    _Context = context;
    _Attrs = attrs;
}

private static int MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED = 100;
private static int DEFAULT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DELAY = 750;

private int mAutoCompleteDelay = DEFAULT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DELAY;
private ProgressBar mLoadingIndicator;

public class mHandler : Handler
{
    public override void HandleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        DelayAutoCompleteTextView.base.PerformFiltering((Java.Lang.ICharSequence)msg.Obj, msg.Arg1);
    }
}

public void setLoadingIndicator(ProgressBar progressBar)
{
    mLoadingIndicator = progressBar;
}

public void setAutoCompleteDelay(int autoCompleteDelay)
{
    mAutoCompleteDelay = autoCompleteDelay;
}

protected override void PerformFiltering(Java.Lang.ICharSequence text, int keyCode)
{
    if (mLoadingIndicator != null)
    {
        mLoadingIndicator.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }

    mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED);
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED, text), mAutoCompleteDelay);
}

public override void OnFilterComplete(int count)
{
    if (mLoadingIndicator != null)
    {
        mLoadingIndicator.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    }

    base.OnFilterComplete(count);
}}
```

But have 3 error messages:

- 1) `DelayAutoCompleteTextView.base.PerformFiltering((Java.Lang.ICharSequence)msg.Obj, msg.Arg1);`
- 2) `mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED);`
- 3) `mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED, text), mAutoCompleteDelay);`

Original code on Java I [copied from github](https://github.com/davidbeloo/CitiesAutoComplete/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/thepinkandroid/citiesautocomplete/general/DelayAutoCompleteTextView.java)

Please help me to convert. 
Sorry for my bad English )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error happens because unlike Java, nested classes in C# are not able to access the parent class's `this` pointer as they are a separate entity.

Instead of making `mHandler` a class, I suggest you make it a variable and use the `Handler(Action<Message>)` constructor to create a `Handler` that can access members of `DelayAutoCompleteTextView`.

```
private readonly Handler mHandler = new Handler(delegate (Message msg) {
    base.PerformFiltering((Java.Lang.ICharSequence)msg.Obj, msg.Arg1);
});
```

---

The second and third errors are simple spelling mistakes.

The Xamarin equivalents of `removeMessages`, `sendMessageDelayed`, `obtainMessage` are simply `RemoveMessages`, `SendMessageDelayed`, `ObtainMessage`, following the `PascalCase` method naming convention outlined by the Microsoft C# coding style guide. *All Xamarin Base Class Libraries and generated bindings for Java libraries follow this convention.*

I also suggest that you change the name of your fields from `mSomeField` to `someField` following the MS C# coding style guide.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have an error, because I don't have access to base (AutoCompleteTextView) class

private readonly Handler mHandler = new Handler(delegate (Message msg) {
    base.PerformFiltering((Java.Lang.ICharSequence)msg.Obj, msg.Arg1);
});

this class on github https://github.com/luckychel/DanfossFindAnalogs/blob/master/DelayAutoCompleteTextView.cs

2 other mistakes has gone, thanks!!!

Comment: @Luckychel try moving the delegate to a method, i.e. Move the contents of the delegate to `private void OnHandlerMessage(Message msg) ` and change the `mHandler` initialization to `new Handler(OnHandlerMessage)`.